# Liquid that melts wood?

Tags: science-based, magic, chemistry

Is it possible to have through *magic* to alter the chemical components of a part of sea water to melt boats?

This is science based since I only need to know what components would *melt* the wood of boats that attempt to cross the line.

Is it possible? If not possible, what component could melt wood if at all?

The rules of magic in my world are the following:

- Magic can only exist if something **can** exist. For instance if a tornado of fire **can** exist then you can devise a sorcery to conjure one up.
- Magic can make new components as long as the composing elements exist and the final component also exists. For instance gunpowder or steel. You can try to create new things by mixing components but it is **dangerous** since magic is unpredictable when experimenting.

To clarify, I know that magic and science-based can be at odds. What I mean is that in this world all magic **has to have** a scientific foundation. In this case the component has to have the **capacity** to exist. ie. you cannot create something that cannot exist composed of existing elements.

So basically for this sorcery to exist it must have been made in a controlled environment by genius chemists, after the magicians will mix the elements magically in the right proportions to get the final product.

Comment: The magic and science-based tags are completely at odds. You seem to be looking for science, as your magic will simply replicate a science approach?

Comment: Since we're talking magic: Yes, it's possible. Please note that the magic tag asks you to define the limits on your magic.

Comment: I clarified a bit more. If it's still not clear I can try to clarify further.

Comment: Relevant: [Could wood ever liquefy?](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=350721) and [Liquid wood?](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/liquid-wood.33249/). Apparently, the Internet likes this question a lot.

Comment: I guess you could make wormholes then? 'Cause they're scientifically stable once they're made, the problem being that there's no way to make them in the first place.

Comment: If you change "melt" to "dissolve", which is kind of similar in it's effect, although chemically completely different, then there's lots of things that do this already.

Comment: Chemistry doesn't really do it. There are chemical compounds that dissolve wood, but they require high temperature to work at reasonable speed, so it would be easier to just burn the ship. Biological enzymes work at reasonable temperatures, but they require cellular machinery to deal with electron capture, so adding the enzymes to sea water probably wouldn't do much. And they'd still take too much time. Just make them burn.

Comment: @Malandy Yes it can be made! They have to know that it can exist first though.

Comment: Theik, SCIENCE AND MAGIC ARE NOT AT ODDS. It's annoying to say so. What he's asking is, if there is some way to dissolve the bottom of a wooden boat by magically changing the water they sail in, what would the science behind it be? Could it be explained in scientific terms, or do we resort to Buffy Speak and cries of "Magic!"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**White liquor will *dissolve* the wood.**

It breaks the bonds between lignin and cellulose in the wood. It's used in the first step of papermaking; [pulping the wood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraft_process). [White liquor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_liquor) is made from Lye ($NaOH$) and sodium sulfide ($Na_2S$). It can be made from seawater, all the components are present. The hydrogen ($H$) and oxygen ($O$) from the water ($H_2O$), sodium ($Na$) is the [second most abundant](https://web.stanford.edu/group/Urchin/mineral.html) mineral in seawater, and sulfur is the fourth most abundant.

You can create both and combine them with some magic.

Comment: Why the downvote? Have a problem with chemistry?

Comment: No idea about the downvote, but doesn't this require significant time at relatively high temperature?

Comment: Although, a zone of boiling sea probably would stop ships...

Comment: @VilleNiemi Delignification by white liquor does not *require* > 100°C, though the process is obviously much faster with higher temperatures.

Comment: I guess we should ask how fast it has to work.. The industrial process takes hours on small chips at temperature above boiling IIRC.

Comment: @VilleNiemi That's correct. I don't know how long it would take to destroy/disable a ship.

Comment: There are 3 answers with downvotes; all the oldest ones, so someone downvoted all answers at that time?. Someone is not understanding the purpose, or is being mean.

Comment: note this will also be lethal to any sea life that swims into it.

Answer (score 6):

Wood doesn't melt.  It burns, acid can eat it away, and it rots and becomes mushy.

So I would recommend turning it into acid to eat holes in the boat, or to cause the rot to take root and spread quickly, making the wood too 'soft' to hold its shape and keep the water out.

Comment: Yep, this.  Melt and wood don't work together.

Comment: How about *enzymes*?

Comment: Yeah what about biological compounds?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligninase

Comment: @Joze plenty of biological compounds that 'digest' wood

Answer (score 4):

How does a wooden ship rot  away normally? It soulds like your magic concept would naturally mimic that process on an accelerated basis.

So don't speak of *melting* the wood, but *denaturing* or *digesting* it. In particular, eaten away by fugus hyphae, which can unravel the [particular "wood" fiber](https://www.wikipedia.org/?title=Wood#Structure) materials (cellulose,  lignin).  See [lignin, biodegredation](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lignin#Biodegradation) for a short answer: *manganese peroxidase and lignin peroxidase*. "Lignin peroxidase... from white-rot fungus Phanerochaete chrysosporium with a variety of lignin-degrading reactions"

Comment: Why the downvote with no explanation?  If this is not a proper answer, please leave a comment so we may learn and edit.

Answer (score 0):

You would need an agent capable of specifically melting/liquefying the cell-wall/apoplast of the wood in question.

Assuming magic, you could theoretically target the apoplast explicitly, say, with a well-placed **Transmute spell**. (But at that point, why not just cast **Liquefy**?)

Assuming science, you'd probably need a technological agent; a **Nanomachine** of some sort, built and coded to target and deconstruct the cell walls specifically...